# Does coordinate wise convex function can be optimized more effectively?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, convex, non-convex

I'm currently working on a non-convex function. It's basically a maximum likelihood problem so I'm trying to optimize this function.

I know that non-convex optimization frequently reaches local optima or saddle points depending on the starting point. However, this function is indeed convex when group of constants are held constant. So one might think of an alternating optimization strategy in which the algorithm updates the parameters alternatively in groups.

Do these algorithms necessarily avoid ending up at saddle points/local optima? or at least reduces the chance ending up in those points?

Answer (score 1):

An alternating optimization strategy like you describe does not avoid local optima. Imagine you have a 2-d objective function $f(x, y)$ where $f(0, 0) = 1$, $f(1,1) = 100$ and the function quickly goes to zero when you move away from from these two points. Say you start at coordinates $(4, 0)$ and hold $y$ fixed. $f(x, 0)$ is convex and will bring you to point $(0, 0)$. But if you alternate to freeze $x$ and optimize $f(0, y)$, you'll still find $f(0,0)$ is the best, and you're stuck!

Non-convex optimization is too much to cover in a single post. There are lots of strategies that do a decent job of trying to avoid local optima. At a high level, this is achieved by saying 'I think this is the global optimum, I've gained enough knowledge about the objective function landscape and haven't found anything better'. If you want an already implemented algorithm, a quick google search for non-convex optimization packages will yield many options. Which one is best depends a lot on what you are optimizing, try a few and see what works.

Comment: Thx for the straightforward example! It really helped understand whats going on.

Comment: In some very specific cases, alternating does work (google Alternating Least Squares Recommender Systems) but most of the time you run into the issue from the example